# How do you write and use a Windows Service in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

How do you write and use a Windows Service in C#? What is the best way to that ?

Comment: Strange, you asked the question then immediately copy/pasted a very long answer. That makes me curious: why did you ask this question?

Comment: @RoyDictus, it's actually allowed - see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions :)

Comment: @Roy it actually is acceptable to ask a question and answer it.. I didn't realise that either until a month or so ago..

Comment: @RoyDictus I like writing tutorials. I used "Answer you question" option. I want to share my knowledge.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too broad. You are asking for a tutorial for an exceedingly broad topic.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan So please help me in improvement of my question - to be good with recommendations

Comment: I'm not suggesting it's not allowed, I just find it strange, especially considering the wording of the question. But that's just me I guess.

Comment: @RoyDictus So please help me in improvement of my question - to be good with recommendations

Comment: How about "How do you write and use a Windows Service in C#?"

Comment: @RoyDictus Do you think that should be a title ?

Comment: It could be both the title _and_ the question. That is just my 2 cents, I think no extra fluff is needed, but it's a free country :-)

Comment: @RoyDictus Better :) ?

Comment: I don't think any editing fixes this. Question is way too broad.

Comment: I would have gone with "Is creating an empty project the best way to create a windows service?" because honestly, this is the 2nd tutorial that doesn't use the 'windows service' template. I tried using the template and I can't find my service in the list of services. Confirming this, net start says 'the service name is invalid'.

Comment: @user426364 I like to create service without template cause then I know there are not any stupid mistakes in my project